# Query the length of a bytea value from PostgreSQL with EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, bytea

In my .NET Core application with Entity Framework Core and Npgsql, I'd like to query records that contain binary data. But sometimes I don't need the actual data but just its length in bytes. That would be something like this query:

```
dbContext.BinaryFiles
    .Select(f => new
    {
        Name = f.Name,
        Length = f.Data.Length
    }
    .ToList();
```

The file class looks like this:

```
public class BinaryFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` contains a `DbSet<BinaryFile>`. The table is defined as:

```
create table binary_files
(
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(200) not null,
    data bytea not null
);
```

When I try this, I get the error: Npgsql.PostgresException: "42883: Function cardinality(bytea) does not exist". The generated query is this:

```
SELECT b.name AS "Name", cardinality(b.data) AS "Length"
FROM binary_files AS b
```

When I try this query interactively instead, I get a result:

```
SELECT b.name AS "Name", LENGTH(b.data) AS "Length"
FROM binary_files AS b
```

So the problem is that the .NET `Array.Length` property isn't translated to the adequate SQL `LENGTH` function but something else instead.

Is this a bug or am I using it incorrectly? How could I get the desired data only?

Versions:

- .NET Core 3.1.1
- Entity Framework Core 3.1.1
- Npgsql 4.1.2
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.0
- PostgreSQL 12 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Npgsql EF provider. `bytea` is not an array type; it's mapped to that as a CLR type, but that doesn't mean the `.Length` property access should be translated to `CARDINALITY`. [This issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1226) seems to match it, given [the test in question](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/test/EFCore.Specification.Tests/Query/GearsOfWarQueryTestBase.cs#L7370).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating Length on byte arrays hasn't been implemented yet... Using https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1226 tracks this. The EF Core main providers (SqlServer and Sqlite) recently merged support for this for 5.0 only as well.